# Corba not sending dynamic String array

Tags: java, corba

I want to send a dynamic String array from the Corba server the client. It works only with static arrays, but I need to get the data from the database so it cannot by prepared statically.

IDL file:

```
module ModData {
  typedef sequence<string> List;
  interface Data {
    List getData();
  };
};
```

Server:

```
public String[] getData() { 
    //This is not working
    String[] data = new String[1];
    data[0] = "xxxx";         

    //This is working
    String[] data = {"xxxx"};
    return data;
}
```

The first option fails with this:

```
com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl convertThrowableToSystemException
WARNING: "IOP00010202: (UNKNOWN) Unknown user exception thrown by the server" org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.runtimeexception(ORBUtilSystemException.java:8869)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.convertThrowableToSystemException(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1936)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1886)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1839)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:274)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1700)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1558)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:940)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:198)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:712)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:469)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1230)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:490)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:519)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ModAuthFIT.ListHelper.write(ListHelper.java:57)
at ModAuthFIT.AuthFITPOA._invoke(AuthFITPOA.java:75)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:653)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:205)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Are you using JacORB? I prefere JacORB than JDK. I think it's not CORBA fault, because you got `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`. Try to debug before the return and see if you got the data correctly.

Comment: I'm using JDK but I've already solved it with a little ugly hack - I've used JSON encoding and transfered the array as a simple string.